# MYSQL CONSTRAINTS

Tags: mysql

How create column in table with constraints to be its input only from group of CHARS
I did like that but it

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UNIVERSITY`.`GRADE REPORT`
(`Student_number` int, 
`Section_id` int, 
`Grade` char  IN ('A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F');
```

Comment: Use ENUM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

To create a column with specific datas (char, int .etc) you can use `ENUM` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html.
I suggest do not use spaces between table name.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UNIVERSITY`.`GRADE_REPORT`(
            `Student_number` int, 
            `Section_id` int, 
            `Grade` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F')
                                                     );
```

You can add default value too:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UNIVERSITY`.`GRADE_REPORT`(
           `Student_number` int, 
           `Section_id` int, 
           `Grade` ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F') DEFAULT 'A'
                                                    );
```

Working Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/9

Not Working Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/10